# How to exclude element inside div from being affected by the div function?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function, web

I want to exclude the **#someButtonHere** from being affected by **#AllContents** onclick function. I try this code, but it doesn't work. 
 Notes: #someButtonHere is of course inside the #AllContents div, but everything need to be affected by the function, except someButton itself.

```
$(function() {
    $('#AllContents').filter(":not(#someButtonHere)").on('click', function() {
    $('#sidebar, #content').addClass('active');
    $('#sidebarCollapse').addClass('change');
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery you can try [event. stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/). Attach this event to your `#someButtonHere` element, something like:

```
$('#someButtonHere').on('click', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  //what else you'd like #someButtonHere to do
});
```

After that you can also remove the `filter()` from your call.